# Import from file with same name but other directory

Tags: python, import

I have two files `/somewhere/main.py` and `/somewhere/repeated_name.py` and then I have other file `/random/path/repeated_name.py`. How do I import a function from `/random/path/repeated_name.py` into `/somewhere/main.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) for that. All you need is the absolute path and then use the `shutil.move(src, dst)`  method. And then you just have to use the `from file import method` without bothering about the folder.

But if you want to import a function to another file, I think this article should answer your question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from somewhere.repeated_name import func_name
```

Just make sure folder also contains an **init**.py, this allows it to be included as a package.